# some webpages not opening in any browser

Tags: 12.04, firefox, websites

I have using *ubuntu 12.04LTS* with all available updates installed. Some websites are not opening in any browser, i have tried many browsers(firefox,chrome,chromium,arora,xxxtrem browser,Midori).

But yesterday i have install the *ubuntu 12.04(the first release of this version)* in my pen drive and use it. In USB booted ubutu, all websites are open properly or **we can say that in older version of browsers websites are opening**(***in usb booted ubuntu firefox version is 11.0***) but now in updated 
 ubuntu 12.04LTS websites are not opening .

I have read some solution about this problem but they are says to change dns server but *i think this is not dns server problem* because with same dns settings websites are opening properly in the windows and usb booted ubutu.

**Please tell what will be solution?**

website which i tried to open are

yahoo.com,
skydrive.live.com,
indiarailinfo.com

Comment: when was the last time you ran an update? plus, what's your chrome version?

Comment: Please provide `/etc/hosts` file or look there.

Comment: danatela how to find this file, when  i run this as a run command then a icon is appear under which /etc/hots is written but when i click on this icon then nothing opens.

Comment: I have found an another sites which not opens in firefox and in other browser (only opens in opera) is sgpc.net

                                                                     
now i have also tried opera which i have uninstalled few month ago.

In opera browser , only skydrive.live.com not opens while other websites got open in opera browser 
 
so what is the problem is other browsers with these sites.

Comment: @user30388, go to the terminal, 

type 'cd /etc'.

then type 'gedit hosts'